# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rules - How can I set a rule when amount > 50 in one category

Tags: magento

I'd like to set a rule for a store.
for example, there is a category 99 (say item A,B is in 99)

when items in 99 in cart is greater than 50, apply a discount.

So,
when subtotal of item A,B > 50, apply
when subtotal of item A,B <= 50, no matter how many other items, don't apply

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

go to actions tab and then go to

```
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions
```

and select category and price condition,please refer below snapshot

[image]

Comment: it is not what I need, because 1. item price is not item total, 2. there would be some items not in category 99 in the cart

Answer (score 1):

I got this.

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If **total amount**  *equals or greater than*  **50**  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:

**Category**  *contains*  **99**

It works in this case.